# Count of current unique values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique

I'm trying to return a `count` of `unique` values in a `pandas df`. It's a cumulative count at each `row`. I'm aiming incorporate a function that determines how many values are currently occurring at any point in time.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : ['8:06:00','11:00:00','11:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','13:30:00','14:00:00','17:00:00'],
    'B' : ['ABC','ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','LMN','DEF','ABC'],          
    'C' : [1,2,1,1,3,1,2,4],            
    })

          A    B  C
0   8:06:00  ABC  1
1  11:00:00  ABC  2
2  11:30:00  DEF  1
3  12:00:00  XYZ  1
4  13:00:00  ABC  3
5  13:30:00  LMN  1
6  14:00:00  DEF  2
7  17:00:00  ABC  4
```

So there are 4 `unique` values in `col['B']`. Which I'm measuring via

```
df1 = df['B'].nunique()
```

But I'm hoping to incorporate a function the `iterates` through the `column` to identify if any specific value occurs again. If not I want the count to decrease. If it's the first time the value appears I want to increase the count. If the value has already appeared and appears again, the count should stay the same. This would display how many values are occurring at any point in time.

Using @jpp's code, we produce the following:

```
cum_maxer = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['B'])[0] + 1).cummax()
df['res'] = cum_maxer - df['B'].duplicated().cumsum()

print(df)
```

Out:

```
          A    B  C  res
0   8:06:00  ABC  1    1
1  11:00:00  ABC  2    0
2  11:30:00  DEF  1    1
3  12:00:00  XYZ  1    2
4  13:00:00  ABC  3    1
5  13:30:00  LMN  1    2
6  14:00:00  DEF  2    1
7  17:00:00  ABC  4    0
```

Intended output for `'res'`

```
0  1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  2
5  3
6  2
7  1
```

Essentially, if the `value` appears for the first time I want to add it to a `cumulative count`. If the value finishes (doesn't appear later on) then the count should decrease. If value has already appeared and appears again the count should stay the same.

Rundown on each row and the intended output:

`1st row`, `ABC` appears for the first time and appears later on. `Count = +1`

`2nd row`, `ABC` appears again so no increase. It also appears later so no decrease. `Count = no change`

`3rd row`, `DEF` appears for the first time and appears later on. `Count = +1`

`4th row`, `XYZ` appears for the first time but doesn't appear later on. At this point in time though, 3 values are occurring so the `count is 3`. The count automatically drops on the next row as `XYZ has finished`

`5th row`, as mentioned above `XYZ` has finished so only `ABC` and `DEF` are currently on. The `ABC` value also appears again so the `count is 2`.

`6th row`, `LMN` appears for the first time so the count increases. This means `ABC, DEF, LMN` are current at the point in time. Much like `row 4`, `LMN` doesn't appear again so the count will decrease on the next row as `LMN` has finished. `Count is 3`

7th row, `DEF` and `ABC` are currently on so the `count is 2`. As `DEF` doesn't appear again the count will decrease on the next row.

8th row, `ABC` the only value currently on so the `count is 1`.

Comment: Why is row `3` not `3 1` in your expected output?

Comment: I'm not tracking - what do you mean "it drops back to 2 as XYZ doesn't appear again"?  Is this some kind of cumulative count or is it a count grouped by each `B` value, or some kind of index?  A bit more explanation would be helpful to understand your final vector.

Comment: I haven't explained it very well but it's a cum count of unique values. I'll change the question now.

Comment: @JeremyAlexander Why do you have `1` and  `1` as the first two rows if ABC is repeated?

Comment: @RafaelC, at each of those rows only 1 value is currently appearing. It goes to `2` on `row 3` because both `ABC` and `DEF` appear later on. It decreases to 2 after `XYZ` because that value doesn't appear again. Think of it as how many values in `Col B` are currently running. Please see the last paragraph in the question.

Comment: @TWrist. weird question. It's related to football. I want to determine how many players are in a certain space at any point in time based of a list of edits.

Comment: Does it make sense @RafaelC?

Comment: @JeremyAlexander Yes it does.. I have added a solution, hope it helps

Comment: I think that it is a valid question. Given that the current profile indicates that the person asking works for a corporation that is a gambling corporation, I would like to know if I am assisiting in anyway either directly or indirectly with an issue that is affecting something to do with gaming.

Comment: I added a new, faster solution. Not sure how important that is. If you need something even faster, it's probably possible via bincounts and indirect indexing in numpy. But this should work reasonably well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `np.unique`

```
u = np.unique(df.B, return_index=True)
df['id'] = df.B.map(dict(zip(*u))) + 1

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    1
```

---

#### Edited Question

For your edited question, here is a solution. First, use `cumcount` in an inverted dataframe to *see the future*

```
df['u'] = df[::-1].groupby('B').B.cumcount()
```

such that `u` says how many times, for each `B`, current `B` appears in the future. Then, `zip` `B` and `u` with your logic, using `S_n = S_{n-1} + new_value + dec`  where `new_value` a flag that is `True` if current `val` is a new value, and `dec` is `True` if previous row was last occurence of that value (i.e. `u==0` at that time). The code would be something like

```
ids = [1]
seen = set([df.iloc[0].B])
dec = False
for val, u in zip(df.B[1:], df.u[1:]):
    ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
    seen.add(val)
    dec = u == 0

df['S'] = ids

    A           B   C   u   S   expected
0   8:06:00     ABC 1   3   1          1
1   11:00:00    ABC 2   2   1          1
2   11:30:00    DEF 1   1   2          2
3   12:00:00    XYZ 1   0   3          3
4   13:00:00    ABC 3   1   2          2
5   13:30:00    LMN 1   0   3          3
6   14:00:00    DEF 2   0   2          2
7   17:00:00    ABC 4   0   1          1
```

where

```
>>> (df.S == df.expected).all()
True
```

---

#### Timings

```
df = pd.DataFrame({          
'A' : ['8:06:00','11:00:00','11:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','13:30:00','14:00:00','17:00:00'],
'B' : ['ABC','ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','LMN','DEF','ABC'],          
'C' : [1,2,1,1,3,1,2,4],            
})

def matt(df):
    valsets = df['B'].apply(lambda x: {x})
    union_sets = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: x | y, 2, 1)
    intersect_count = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: len(x & y), 2, 1)

    seen = union_sets.accumulate(valsets, dtype=np.object)
    to_be_seen = union_sets.accumulate(valsets[::-1], dtype=np.object)[::-1]
    df['res'] = intersect_count(seen, to_be_seen)
    return df

def raf(df):
    ids = [1]
    seen = set([df.iloc[0].B])
    dec = False
    df['u'] = df[::-1].groupby('B').B.cumcount()
    for val, u in zip(df.B[1:], df.u[1:]):
        ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
        seen.add(val)
        dec = u == 0

    df['S'] = ids
    return df

df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index()
```

#### Results

```
%timeit matt(df)
168 ms ± 12.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit raf(df)
64.2 ms ± 2.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to allocate an integer identifier to each unique value, then use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cummax.html) on the result for a rolling count.

```
df['id'] = pd.factorize(df['B'])[0] + 1
df['count'] = df['id'].cummax()

print(df)

          A    B  C  id  count
0   8:06:00  ABC  1   1      1
1  11:00:00  DEF  1   2      2
2  12:00:00  XYZ  1   3      3
3  13:00:00  ABC  2   1      3
4  13:30:00  LMN  1   4      4
5  14:00:00  DEF  2   2      4
6  17:00:00  ABC  3   1      4
```

---

**Update**

For your desired output, you can calculate the `cummax` as before and subtract a cumulative count of duplicates:

```
cum_maxer = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['B'])[0] + 1).cummax()
df['res'] = cum_maxer - df['B'].duplicated().cumsum()

print(df)

          A    B  C  res
0   8:06:00  ABC  1    1
1  11:00:00  DEF  1    2
2  12:00:00  XYZ  1    3
3  13:00:00  ABC  2    2
4  13:30:00  LMN  1    3
5  14:00:00  DEF  2    2
6  17:00:00  ABC  3    1
```

Comment: This is great. Is there any way to determine the `cumulative count` that decreases if the `value` in `Col B` has finished?

Comment: Thanks @jpp. This is brilliant but it doesn't decrease until a maximum value is reached. Please see updated question. You have answered the first question so I'm happy to award the bounty and post another problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain mate but this doesn't work either. I understand you can only go off the example dataset but the code has to be something like the description. i.e iterate through and check for future values, if not decrease. As mentioned previously I'm happy to award the bounty. This is my fault. I'll update the question again.

Comment: @JeremyAlexander, I'm not worried about the bounty, just trying to get at what you want! The output seems the same and the logic with `cumsum` seems to match your text description.

Answer (score 1):

**Update with faster answer**

I wish I had noticed @RafaelC's `groupby.cumcount()` technique before I gave the answer below. That gave me an idea for a faster method. As @RafaelC noticed, there's no need to work with a full list of observations as you work through the rows; it's enough just to know how many times the current symbol appears earlier or later. In fact, as you noted in your update, all you really need to know is whether the symbol on the current row has just appeared for the first time (add 1 to the count) and whether the symbol on the previous row just appeared for the last time (subtract 1 from the count). With that in mind, you can use this fairly simple and streamlined code:

import numpy as np, pandas as pd

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : ['8:06:00','11:00:00','11:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','13:30:00','14:00:00','17:00:00'],
    'B' : ['ABC','ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','LMN','DEF','ABC'],          
    'C' : [1,2,1,1,3,1,2,4],            
})

groups = df.groupby('B')['B']
# flag the first and last appearance of each symbol
first_appearance = (groups.cumcount() == 0).astype(int)
last_appearance = (groups.cumcount(False) == 0).astype(int)
# delay effect of last_appearance by one step
last_appearance = pd.np.concatenate(([0], last_appearance.values[:-1]))
df['res'] = (first_appearance - last_appearance).cumsum()
print df
#           A    B  C  res
# 0   8:06:00  ABC  1    1
# 1  11:00:00  ABC  2    1
# 2  11:30:00  DEF  1    2
# 3  12:00:00  XYZ  1    3
# 4  13:00:00  ABC  3    2
# 5  13:30:00  LMN  1    3
# 6  14:00:00  DEF  2    2
# 7  17:00:00  ABC  4    1
```

Calling this `matthias2` and re-running @RafaelC's benchmarks gives the following results:

```
%timeit matthias1(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
%timeit raf(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 230 ms per loop
%timeit matthias2(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 7 ms per loop
```

**Original answer, relatively slow**

How about the code below? The idea of this is to use two cumulative sets: one shows all the items that have been seen from the start of the list to the present point, and one shows everything that is yet to be seen in the list. The latter set can be created the same way as the first, just by reversing the list, building the cumulative sets, then reversing the list again.

Pandas doesn't have a generalized `accumulate` function to do this. You could probably get there with `pd.Series.expanding`, but that re-accumulates large slices of the series at each step, which creates a slow n^2 time dependency. So I used `numpy`'s `accumulate` function to build the sets, as shown below. This should run pretty efficiently and be about as clear.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : ['8:06:00','11:00:00','11:30:00','12:00:00','13:00:00','13:30:00','14:00:00','17:00:00'],
    'B' : ['ABC','ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','LMN','DEF','ABC'],          
    'C' : [1,2,1,1,3,1,2,4],            
})

# convert individual values to sets to make the next steps easier
valsets = df['B'].apply(lambda x: {x})

# define numpy ufuncs to get union of sets and size of intersection of sets
# note that union_sets.accumulate() will give a "cumulative union" of sets
union_sets = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: x | y, 2, 1)
intersect_count = np.frompyfunc(lambda x, y: len(x & y), 2, 1)

# create numpy vectors showing how many unique values have been seen up to 
# each point, and how many will be seen from there to the end
seen = union_sets.accumulate(valsets, dtype=np.object)
to_be_seen = union_sets.accumulate(valsets[::-1], dtype=np.object)[::-1]

# count how many are in both the have-been-seen and to-be-seen sets
df['res'] = intersect_count(seen, to_be_seen)

# add intermediate vectors for illustration
df['seen'] = seen
df['to_be_seen'] = to_be_seen

print(df)
          A    B  C res                  seen            to_be_seen
0   8:06:00  ABC  1   1                 {ABC}  {XYZ, ABC, DEF, LMN}
1  11:00:00  ABC  2   1                 {ABC}  {XYZ, ABC, LMN, DEF}
2  11:30:00  DEF  1   2            {ABC, DEF}  {XYZ, ABC, DEF, LMN}
3  12:00:00  XYZ  1   3       {XYZ, ABC, DEF}  {XYZ, ABC, LMN, DEF}
4  13:00:00  ABC  3   2       {XYZ, ABC, DEF}       {ABC, DEF, LMN}
5  13:30:00  LMN  1   3  {XYZ, ABC, LMN, DEF}       {ABC, LMN, DEF}
6  14:00:00  DEF  2   2  {XYZ, ABC, DEF, LMN}            {ABC, DEF}
7  17:00:00  ABC  4   1  {XYZ, ABC, LMN, DEF}                 {ABC}
```

Note that I stored the intermediate vectors in the dataframe so you can see how the algorithm works. But there's no need to do that in your production code.